# Test battery status using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm trying to use PowerShell to tell me when my computer is on battery or AC Power.

I want my script to send me a windows notification when my laptop's charger unplugs.

For the moment, I try to use a recursive fonction to test my battery status every 5 seconds but it doesn't work...

Please, be indulgent about my level, I didn't know anything about PowerShell 3 hours ago... And the last time I coded something was a long time ago !

```
Function Test-IsOnBattery
{

$battery = Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery

If ($battery.BatteryStatus -eq 2) {
    
    Write-Host "PC sur secteur."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    return Test-IsOnBattery
    }

Else {
    
    Write-Host "PC sur batterie."

    New-BurntToastNotification -Text "Battery Notification" , "Batterie plus sur secteur !"
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is "_but it doesn't work..._"? Do you get errors? What happens/what not?

Comment: Your function looks good to me. Just tested it and works fine. I would definitely use a `while` loop instead of recursion but aside from that looks good

Comment: PowerShell does not have anything in the way of tail-call optimization. Using recursion to implement a possibly unbounded loop is definitely going to exhaust the stack sooner or later, so don't do it. There's no actual need to in this case either, in that it doesn't make the code any simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan,

Here's a script you can use that you can run from a Scheduled Task, rather than a loop, and have it start on boot up and repeat every so many minutes.

```
<#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | PowerShell Pgm: BatteryStatus.ps1                                         |
  | Programmed By : The Computer Mentor                                       |
  |           aka : RetiredGeek @ askWoody.com & StackOverFlow.com            |
  | Created       : 06 Mar 2013                                               |
  | Last Updated  : 23 Jan 2023                                               |          |
  | Current Ver.  : 6.0                                                       |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#>

Clear-Host

Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
$StatusMsg = {
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Message, $Title,
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK ,
  [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)}

$Message = ""
$Title   = "Battery Status:"

<#+-----------------------------------------------------+
  | BatterStatus Values                                 |
  |Other   (1)  The battery is discharging.             |
  |Unknown (2)  The system has access to AC so no       |
  |             battery is being discharged. However,   |
  |             the battery is not necessarily charging.|
  |Fully Charged (3)                                    |
  |Low (4)                                              |
  |Critical (5)                                         |
  |Charging (6)                                         |
  |Charging and High (7)                                |
  |Charging and Low (8)                                 |
  |Charging and Critical (9)                            |
  |Undefined (10)                                       |
  |Partially Charged (11)                               |
  +-----------------------------------------------------|#> 

$GWArgs = @{ Class        = "Win32_Battery"
             ComputerName = "LocalHost" 
           }

$MyBattery = Get-CIMInstance @GWArgs

If ($Null -eq $MyBattery) {
  $Message = "No Battery Present"
}

Else {

  $BatteryRemaining = [Int]$MyBattery.EstimatedChargeRemaining
  
  if(($BatteryRemaining -lt 30) -and 
      $($MyBattery.BatteryStatus) -eq 1) {
     $Message = "Battery Low...Please Charge Me!"
  }
  Elseif(($BatteryRemaining -gt 90) -and 
          $($MyBattery.BatteryStatus) -ne 1) {
             $Message = 
             "Battery CHARGED above 90%...Please Unplug Me!"
  }

} #End Else

if($Message -ne "") {
  $Null = & $StatusMsg
}

<#
  +----------------------------------------------------------+
  | Notes:                                                   |
  | 1. To call as a scheduled task do the following in the   |
  |    Action Pane                                           |
  |   A. Action:                   Start a Program           |
  |   B. Program/script:           powershell.exe            |
  |   D. Set the Trigger run At Logon and then repeat        |
  |      every few minutes.                                  |
  +----------------------------------------------------------+
#>
```

If you want to use Toast msgs. just replace that logic where I have my $StatusMgs lines.